# Javascript regex replace yields unexpected result

Tags: javascript, regex

I have this strange issue, hope that someone will explain what is going on.

My intention is to capture the textual part (a-z, hyphen, underscore) and append the numeric values of `id` and `v` to it, underscore separated.

My code:

```
var str_1 = 'foo1_2';
var str_2 = 'foo-bar1_2';
var str_3 = 'foo_baz1_2';
var id = 3;
var v = 2;
str_1 = str_1.replace(/([a-z_-]+)\d+/,'$1' + id + '_' + v);
str_2 = str_2.replace(/([a-z_-]+)\d+/,'$1' + id + '_' + v);
str_3 = str_3.replace(/([a-z_-]+)\d+/,'$1' + id + '_' + v);

$('#test').html(str_1 + '<br>' + str_2 + '<br>' + str_3 + '<br>');
```

Expected result:

```
foo3_2
foo-bar3_2
foo_baz3_2
```

Actual Result:

```
foo3_2_2
foo-bar3_2_2
foo_baz3_2_2
```

Any ideas?

[JS Fiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/txwuquxv/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your pattern:

```
/([a-z_-]+)\d+/
```

matches only "foo1" in "foo1_2", and "foo" will be the value of the captured group. The `.replace()` function replaces the portion of the source string that was actually matched, leaving the remainder alone. Thus "foo1" is replaced by "foo3_2", but the original trailing "_2" is still there as well.

If you want to alter the entire string, then your regular expression will have to account for everything in the source strings.

Comment: Ah! I feel so stupid right now.. knew it was something obvious. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Just try with:

```
str_1 = str_1.match(/([a-z_-]+)\d+/)[1] + id + '_' + v;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this instead to capture 1_2 completely:

```
str_1 = str_1.replace(/([a-z_-]+)\d+_\d+/,'$1' + id + '_' + v);
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you want to replace `_2` also of string. Solution can be this:

```
str_1 = str_1.replace(/([a-z_-]+)\d+_\d/,'$1' + id + '_' + v);
str_2 = str_2.replace(/([a-z_-]+)\d+_\d/,'$1' + id + '_' + v);
str_3 = str_3.replace(/([a-z_-]+)\d+_\d/,'$1' + id + '_' + v);
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/txwuquxv/3/)

Comment: thank you, I got it figured. @Pointy beat you to it.

Answer (score 0):

Your pattern actually includes the first digits, but it will store only the textual part into $1:

```
foo1_2

([a-z_-]+)\d+   = foo1
$1              = foo
```

The pattern stops searching at the first digits of the string.
if you want to replace any characters after the textual part, you could use this pattern:

```
/([a-z_-]+)\d+.*/
```